# MissingMethodException on domain class save in Grails 1.3.7

Tags: grails

I'm having a problem calling the save method on a domain object. The error is:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static my.awesome.Class.FeedHit.save() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: save(), save(java.lang.Boolean), save(java.util.Map), wait(), any(), wait(long)
```

I'm going through an array of FeedHits, updating a flag, and then calling the save method:

```
void updateFeedHits(Set<FeedHit> list, FeedHitStatus status) {
    for (FeedHit feedHit: list) {
        feedHit.status = status
        try {
            feedHit.save()
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.info("unknown exception during update FeedHit", ex)
        }
    }
}
```

I've seen other StackOVerflow users have the same problem, but only during tests. This code is in normal release code.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

Here is the FeedHit object, slightly edited.

```
class FeedHit {

    Feed feed
    String title
    String body
    String url
    FeedHitStatus status
    String sourceId
    String hash
    Date publishedDate
    Date dateCreated = new Date()
    Integer pos = -1

    static constraints = {
        alert(nullable: true)
        title(nullable: true)
        body(nullable: true)
        url(nullable: true)
        status(nullable: true)
        sourceId(nullable: true)
        hash(nullable: true)
        pos(nullable: true)
        publishedDate(nullable: true)
        dateCreated(nullable: true)
    }

    static mapping = {
        table('alert_hit')
        autoTimestamp false
        version(false)
        alert(column: 'alert_id')
        body(sqlType: 'text')
        url(sqlType: 'text')
        sourceId(column: 'sourceId')
        publishedDate(column: 'publishedDate')
        dateCreated(column: 'dateCreated')
    }

    /**
     * Generates a hash from title, body and url.
     */
    public AlertHit generateHash() {
         StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        if (this.title != null) {
            sb.append(this.title);
        }
        if (this.body != null) {
            sb.append(this.body);
        }
        if (this.url != null) {
            sb.append(this.url);
        }
        if (this.publishedDate != null) {
            sb.append(this.publishedDate.getTime());
        }
        if (sb.length() > 0) {
            hash = Md5Hash.hash(sb.toString());
        }
        this
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "AlertHit{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", alert=" + alert +
            ", title='" + title + '\'' +
            ", body='" + body + '\'' +
            ", url='" + url + '\'' +
            ", status=" + status +
            ", sourceId='" + sourceId + '\'' +
            ", hash='" + hash + '\'' +
            ", publishedDate=" + publishedDate +
            ", dateCreated=" + dateCreated +
            ", pos=" + pos +
            ", version=" + version +
            '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `alertHit` here and where is it declared?

Comment: Could you post the domain object?

Comment: In what time do you call updateFeedHits method?

Comment: @IanRoberts: copy-paste error

Comment: @chalimartines: A thread is created/started when tomcat starts. This thread will wake up and then check a URL for data. When data is detected, the FeedHit object will be created and saved with the above code. It is in a service class.

Comment: You need to manually annotate gorm functions, if you use domain classes outside grails context.

Comment: We had same issue when this kind of thread started use GORM objects before grails context was properly initialised. Our solution was to move thread start to Bootstrap in grails conf directory. I'm not sure whether same way is possible with grails 1.x we have 2.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to annotate GORM functions, if you want to use domain class outside grails. See http://www.rimerosolutions.com/using-gorm-standalone-outside-grails/

I would recommend you to use another way than native threads. Try: [Quartz-Plugin](http://grails.org/plugins/quartz)

Comment: Quartz Plugin is already used. I was simplifying the example. And upon further inspection, the save() function was NOT in a service. The joys of debugging other people code, long after they have left. Refactoring the code to put the save back into grails resolved this problem.